# Mock AWS Gateway RestApi

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, jestjs, aws-api-gateway

I write an UT for creating ApiGateway RestApi.
This is the undertest code :

```
new RestApi(this, 'rest-api-2', {
    restApiName: this.app.name('RestAPI'),
    deployOptions: {
        dataTraceEnabled: true,
        loggingLevel: MethodLoggingLevel.INFO
    }
})
```

And this is the UT code which mockes RestaPI and tests if called with correct parameter:

```
import { MethodLoggingLevel, RestApi } from '@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway'
jest.mock('@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway')
jest.mock('@aws-cdk/core/lib/construct-compat')

class MinimalApp extends BaseApp {
  addConstructs (): void {
    // No need additional constructs
  }

  get persistentStack (): StackContainer {
    return {
      region: 'us-east-1',
      account: '12345'
    } as unknown as StackContainer
  }
}
  let restApi: RestApi
  restApi = {
      restApiId: 'rest-api',
      root: {
        addResource: jest.fn().mockImplementation()
      }
    } as unknown as RestApi
    mocked(RestApi).mockReturnValue(restApi)
    mocked(app.name).mockReturnValue(restApiName)
  }

  describe('createRestApi', () => {
    it('should create the rest api', function () {
      expect(RestApi).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        app.persistentStack,
        restApiId,
        {
          deployOptions: {
            dataTraceEnabled: true,
            loggingLevel: MethodLoggingLevel.INFO
          }
        }
      )
    })
  })
```

It is failing with this message :

```
- Expected
+ Received

- Object {
-   "account": "12345",
-   "region": "us-east-1",
+ RestApiConstruct {
+   "api": Object {
+     "restApiId": "rest-api-2",
+     "root": Object {
+       "addResource": [Function mockConstructor],
+     },
+   },
+   "app": MinimalApp {
+     "addConstructInitializer": [Function addConstructInitializer],
+     "build": [Function build],
...
```

I was mocking Cognito User Pool with similar code. But looks like RestAPI is not being mocked. How can i mock it correctly?

Comment: Where does `RestApi` come from? Show the code

Comment: Added the RestApi declaration code